# Is it necessary to sanitize data for Firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-authentication

I have a form that takes in an email and password in plain text and calls the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password.trim())` function.

Do I need to sanitize the email input for security, or does Firebase take care of this? (Firebase hashes the passwords, so sanitizing the password input shouldn't be an issue.)

Any piece of documentation which explains Firebase's protocol is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication handles everything related to security.  You simply invoke the APIs as documented.